# Sorting posts alphabetically in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

Using [this information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts) from the WordPress Codex I try to sort posts alphabetically in WordPress, now working on the search results.

This is the default code from the template, that works for searching but comes up with a reversed chronological order by default:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', apptheme_get_list_type() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now, I tried changing it to this:

```
<?php

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        $sorted_posts = get_posts( $args );
    endwhile;

?>

<?php foreach ($sorted_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', apptheme_get_list_type() ); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which works regarding the sort order, but it gives back all posts instead of just the ones that fit to the search. What parameter should I change? (I am familiar with PHP but this is my first time modifying a WordPress template)

Thanks!

Comment: `'posts_per_page' => -1` gives you all posts back. Just define a number there instead and youll only get that number back.

Comment: Full list of arguments for queries can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Most of what is written on that codex page is just a lot of crap. Sadly, that is not the only page in the codex that is total crap. Go back to your main/original loop. You should not be running custom queries in place of the main query. Once you are back to the main loop on **all* pages, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to suite your needs

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but it should work:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','custom_search_sort_custom',10,2);
function custom_search_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_search()) 
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type ASC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title ASC";

    return  $orderby;
}
```